# Fill non-existing rows in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill missing rows into my data frame.

I have two lists:

```
a = ["a", "b"]  # column a
b = ["e", "f"]  # column b
```

and a data frame:

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame([{"a": "a", "b": "e", "c": 5}])
```

I'll do some group by and aggregation on my existing columns:

```
result = data_frame.groupby(["a", "b"])["c"].sum().reset_index()
```

and the result looks like this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | e | 5 |

But what I want to achieve is to fill in the missing combinations of the list a and b, so that my table looks like this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | e | 5 |
| a | f | 0 |
| b | e | 0 |
| b | f | 0 |

I somehow made it work with this piece of code:

```
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i not in result["a"] and j not in result["b"]:
            result = pd.concat([
                result,
                pd.DataFrame([{"a": i, "b": j, "c": 0}])
            ])
```

But I feel that this is not very elegant. Is there a better way to fill in all combinations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on the [product](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) of the lists.

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, b])
grouped = df.groupby(["a", "b"])["c"].sum()
grouped.reindex(mi, fill_value=0)
```

```
a  e    5
   f    0
b  e    0
   f    0
Name: c, dtype: int64
```